# PJSip crashing, No stacktrace in my android studio logs

Tags: android, pjsip

I've started working with pjsip in the last week. The most difficulty I've faced so far is debugging the crash. So currently my app is crashing and I'm not getting any information in the log except just this line

> A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00006b14 (code=-6), thread 27412

It's clearly not enough information to debug the issue.

So is there is any other way i can get stacktrace of crash in my android studio log?

Comment: Looks like you've got a native crash. Those never print on the filter for a specific application for some reason (or at least they don't in my experience). Try looking for it with no filters. Alternatively, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13132238) might be able to help you find the logs

Comment: are you found any solution to this issue?